# Why do computer science students learn electronics and electric circuit analysis?

Tags: programming

I am a student of BS(CS), There are two courses that I don't understand why they are in our scheme? As we know that in CS we learn programming courses. Our concern is with programming languages like python, C++, Java, Html, CSS and so on. But I can't see the use of these two courses which are belong to Electrical Engineering. Why are these two courses in our scheme?

Comment: This seems like a local issue, not a general one. It seems unusual to me as do the number of languages (too high). Perhaps you should ask this question of your faculty who designed the program.

Comment: First note: computer-science ≠programming. Computer science is about much more than programming.

Comment: An embedded developer might be asking why they need to learn more than C/ASM, and how the other 90% of the product actually works.

Comment: If this question is not a duplicate, please edit it to make clearer how it is different and the question can be reopened.

Comment: I don't actually think it is a duplicate exactly, but the answers to the other question probably apply to this one also. Perhaps with additional force.

Comment: @Buffy It might not be. Either way, I'd love some clarification from OP.